# Routes repeating itself in address bar

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redirect, mongoose, routes

I am new to MEAN stack. I want my routes to look like this in the address bar. 
'localhost:3000/user/login','localhost:3000/user/signup','localhost:3000/vendor/login','localhost:3000/vendor/signup'. I have configured my routes for user like this.

```
 var userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
 app.use('/user', userRoutes);
```

and the routes in user.js  is as follows.

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res){
    var user = new User();

    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.picture = user.avatar();
    user.address = req.body.address;

    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, existingUser){
        if(existingUser){
            req.flash('errors', 'Account with this email Id already exists!!');
            return res.redirect('/signup');
        }else{
            user.save(function(err, user){
                if(err) return next(err);

                req.logIn(user, function(err){
                    if(err) return next(err);
                    res.redirect('/profile');
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In the above code if use a registered email-id,i am getting redirected to 'localhost:3000/signup', but I want to redirect it to 'localhost:3000/user/signup'. And if I am putting res.redirect code as follows

```
req.flash('errors', 'Account with this email Id already exists!!');
            return res.redirect('user/signup');
```

then I am getting redirected to 'localhost:3000/user/user/signup'. How do I redirect it to 'localhost:3000/user/signup'

Comment: Try: return res.redirect('/user/signup'); instead

Comment: try res.redirect('signup').